# Is it possible to specify lower bound in response variable during smooth with gam?

Tags: r, smoothing, gam, mgcv

I am trying to fit a smoothed surface of `z` against `x` and `y` using formula `z ~ s(x, y)` with `gam` function
 in `mgcv` package. My goal is to predict response `z` based on new values of `x` and `y`.

In my real situation, `z` should be a positive number negative `z` would be meaningless. However, the predicted `z`s
are sometimes negative. It seems that for some region, there is not enough points in the training data to estimate `z`
accurately.

My question is: **Is there a way to specifiy a lower bound of `z` during smooth in `gam` so that later I won't get negative `z`s with `predict`?**

Below is a minimal example that reproduces this issue.

```
library(mgcv)

x <- seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.01)
y <- seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.01)
dtt <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)

set.seed(123)
dtt$xp <- dtt$x + rnorm(nrow(dtt)) / 100
dtt$yp <- dtt$y + rnorm(nrow(dtt)) / 100

dtt$z <- 1 / (dtt$xp^2 + dtt$yp^2)

m <- sample.int(nrow(dtt), 3000)

dtt.train <- dtt[m, ]
dtt.test <- dtt[!(1:nrow(dtt) %in% m), ]

fit <- gam(z ~ s(x, y), data = dtt.train)

p <- predict(fit, newdata = dtt.test)

plot(dtt.test$z, p, xlab = 'Real', ylab = 'Predicted', pch = 19, col = 1 + (p < 0))
abline(h = 0, v = 0)
```

As you can see, for the red points. the real values are positive but the predicted values are negative.

[image]

Comment: I think family and link function is one of the options, such as `gam(z ~ s(x, y), data = dtt.train, family = "gaussian"(link = "log"))`

Comment: @cuttlefish44, thanks for the hint. I tried `log` link but the predicuted `z` still have many negative values. It seems that the predicted values are transformed by the link function so that I have to apply the mean function myself to obtain correct `z` values?

Comment: I figured it out. The default return value of `predict.gam` is linear predicotor. When the link funcitoion is identity, the linear predictor is in the same scale with `z`. When the link is `log`, I have to specify `type = "response"` in `predict.gam` to get preicted `z` values.